# Artemis AMQ119213: User: '' does not have permission='CONSUME'

Tags: permissions, activemq-artemis, amq

I need to create an user who is just used to create queues from CI/CD tool.

```
<permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq, opadmin"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq, opadmin"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq, opadmin"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="amq, developer"/>
```

**i am getting below error**

> [amq-broker@x01sipscnaq1a bin]$ ./artemis queue create
>   --auto-create-address --durable --user opadmin --password xxxxxxxx --anycast --preserve-on-no-consumers --url tcp://10.91.xxx.xxx:61716 Exception in thread "main"
>   ActiveMQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION
>   message=AMQ119213: User: opadmin does not have permission='CONSUME'
>   for queue activemq.management.383ccac9-0084-4c44-8f23-7f5c44f7b0dc on
>   address
>   activemq.management.383ccac9-0084-4c44-8f23-7f5c44f7b0dc.activemq.management.383ccac9-0084-4c44-8f23-7f5c44f7b0dc]

**So changed to**

```
<permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq, opadmin"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq, opadmin"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq, opadmin"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="amq, developer, opadmin"/>
```

**It goes in with no error, but hangs (waited for more than 30 minutes)**

> [amq-broker@x01sipscnaq1a bin]$ ./artemis queue create --silent
>   --auto-create-address --durable --user opadmin --password xxxxxx --anycast --name TestTorture --preserve-on-no-consumers --url tcp://10.91.xxx.xxx:61716 --verbose Executing
>   org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.queue.CreateQueue queue
>   create --silent --auto-create-address --durable --user opadmin
>   --password xxxxxx --anycast --name TestTorture --preserve-on-no-consumers --url tcp://10.91.xxx.xxx:61716 --verbose Home::/opt/redhat/amq-broker-7.1.0-hf8,
>   Instance::/opt/redhat/amq-config/cn_soi/broker2b
>   ^C[amq-broker@x01sipscnaq1a bin]$

Comment: What is the "match" for the permissions you pasted?

Comment: HI Justin, it is default match="#"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any user performing remote management operations via core messages (e.g. the Artemis CLI) needs the following permissions on `activemq.management.#`:

- `createNonDurableQueue` (to create a "subscription" queue on the management address in order to receive the management reply)
- `consume` (to receive the management reply)
- `send` (to send the management message)
- `manage` (to perform a management operation)

You are missing the `send` and `manage` operations.  While the client might not receive exceptions about this since it is sending non-durable messages (which are fire-and-forget) the log on the broker should contain the relevant errors.

Comment: Hi @Justin , Thanks a lot. I gave all admin permissions to new user and able to create the address. 
I am using 7.1 version. Can you help on below. 
1) Is it possible to create read only user for management console.
2) Deleted address says Address doesn't exist but visible in stat and console.

Comment: I recommend you create new questions for additional issues. Comments aren't designed to be used for this purpose.